# Javascript Error: Permission denied to access property 'resizeTo'

Tags: javascript

I am using Firebug's console to learn Javascript and when i poped up a window like this:

> `var googleWindow= window.open("http://www.google.com","Dogs window","height = 300, width = 300, top = 100, left = 100");`

then i tried to resize it like this: `googleWindow.resizeTo()` and I got an Error.

I have read for other methods of window that may be disabled (eg. moveTo() ) and indeed i got undefined when i tried to use them. But what happened with this?

Comment: you can't access the window if it's from another domain.

Comment: But I can! The first part is working for whatever i tried. even google.com. I get error only when i call resizeTo(). The popup is already opened.

Comment: yes it is working because you are creating a new object of window.once it is loaded you wont be able to use resizeTo()

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: FYI, you should never have a space in the window name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code running on your website is not allowed to ask the browser to execute JavaScript functions on Google's web pages. If it was, the security implications would be hideous.

Comment: That was just a placeholder! I put other urls too.

Comment: For "Google's web pages" read "any webpage on a different origin"

Comment: you can use resizeTo() only if popup is in you working domain.

Comment: Quentin, google was just an example. I tried other urls too. Maybe Amit is right. That means i can't test these methods from firebug, right?

Comment: @AntonisGrigoriadis Google, Yahoo, Etc, it does not matter. Any website that is from a different domain than the current page is going to throw these security errors. Read my same origin link I posted in the comments under your question.